# calling a php namespace with a variable

Tags: php, variables, namespaces

I'm learning to use the namespaces in php, and I am trying to put a variable in the namespace name when calling a constant.
Here is my code.

fruits2.php

```
<?php
namespace fruits\red;
const redfruit = 'tomato';
```

fruits1.php

```
<?php
namespace fruits;

require_once('fruits2.php');

const myconst = 'banana';

echo myconst; // displays banana

echo '<br>';

echo \fruits\red\redfruit; // displays tomato

echo '<br>';
$color = 'red';
echo \fruits\$color\redfruit; // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$color' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

I don't understand how I can call the constant in this last line. I tried with the following but it is considered as a simple string.

```
echo '\fruits\\'.$color.'\\redfruit';
```

I'm pretty sure that I should be able to do it, because I could do something very similar when calling a class in another part of this code:

```
$name = '\fruits\basket\\'.$color.'\\eat';
$c = new $name(); //this works
```

Anybody knows the answer to that? Thanks!

Comment: you can't because your not allowed to put variable where ever you want, such as  `class foo extends $var{ .. }` that's not gonna work either.  Same with `public function $var( $a, $b )` somethings you just aren't supposed to do, even PHP needs to have rules, Man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `constant` keyword:

```
$name = constant("fruits\\$color\\redfruit");
```

You have to escape the slashes.
Also the name has to be fully qualified (relative to the root namespace).